# prevent popup menu of parent control from showing

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I assigned a popup menu to the TPageControl because I want to display it when I rightclick a tab.

So that works...

Unfortunately it also shows the popup menu when I right-click within the actual tab sheet.

This I do not want because my ListBox1 in the tab sheet responds to a right-click to execute some code.

So right now it's a mess, the code fires upon rightclick of the listbox but also then displays a popup menu.

How can I nullify this popup menu in the tabsheet or at least within the listbox itself?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnContextPopup

Answer (score 0):

ok, Handled := True; was all that was needed in the popup event of the listbox. Thanks Rufo for pointing me in the right direction.